# Is there a way to generate new `models.py` based on migration files in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-south

Say you have an old `models.py` and dozens of `00**_foo_bar.py` migration files, and now you want a fresh start. Is there a way/command to automatically generate a new `models.py` based on old `models.py` and those migration files?

Comment: I understand you might want to reset the migrations, but why do you need a new models file? The migrations represent the steps needed to get to the current state of models.py, there shouldn't be any changes from what's currently there.

Answer (score 0):

Your models files should be up to date - if there have been multiple migrations, they were caused by changes to the model files.  In that case, you should look into squashing your migrations, which is easy - as long as you don't have any deployments out there that you're leaving in the cold (i.e. a deployment exists on migration 15 and you squash 0-20 together.  How do they find their way to migration 20?)

Migrations Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#squashing-migrations

Now, if you have a database (usually legacy) but you want to generate models.py, you can use the inspectdb command.  Keep in mind - this will not encode custom behavior and makes a lot of guesses about data types, but it can be a good start.  Docs below.

Inspect DB: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-inspectdb